# Pushbullet no longer working with Matlab (error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed)

Tags: matlab, pushbullet

I was using Pushbullet with Matlab 2018a without issues until recently. Then I started getting the following error:

> Error using webwrite (line 136)
> Could not establish a secure connection to "api.pushbullet.com". The reason is "error:14090086:SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed". Check your certificate file ([rootcerts.pem]) for expired, missing or invalid certificates.

I tried using
`options.CertificateFilename=('');`

before the line
`output = webwrite([self.HOST,self.PUSH_URL],data,options);`

This solution worked for a while but now, I get

> Error using readContentFromWebService (line 46)
> The server returned the status 403 with message "Forbidden" in response to the request to URL https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes.

Any suggestions? Thanks